# Hiding shared library calls from ltrace

Tags: c, dynamic-linking

I am trying to implement some antidebug methods. Although I have encrypted texts, `ltrace` reveals them, for example:

```
strstr("Name:\tltrace\n", "ltrace")
```

A solution would be static linking, but I do not want to statically link everything. Is there a way to select which functions to link statically, or to prevent `ltrace` from revealing these information?

Comment: Thank you downvoter. Can you write a comment too or just pressing the downvote button?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to select which functions to link statically

That's a question for https://stackoverflow.com/

> or to prevent `ltrace` from revealing these information

You could have your program try to find and terminate running `ltrace` processes. But this has limited use if your process doesn't have sufficient privileges or if the user renames `ltrace` or if the user patches out (disables) your `ltrace`-termination code.

Comment: (And as a side comment, having your program terminate or interfere with users' other processes at runtime is likely to make for very unhappy users.)

Answer (score 0):

`ltrace` uses `ptrace` to patch instructions in the original binary to a breakpoint. This is specifically done to every `plt` entry in the dynamically linked binary. The `plt` entries contain a small piece of code to resolve and jump to the function being called.

You can probably write code in your program to do the opposite and restore every breakpoint after `ltrace` has patched it. See [`arch_enable_breakpoint`](https://gitlab.com/cespedes/ltrace/-/blob/main/sysdeps/linux-gnu/breakpoint.c?ref_type=heads#L41) in the `ltrace` source